# why isn't "which mysql" isn't showing the rest of the path defined in .bash_profile?

Tags: mysql, path, bash

This is listed in my .bash_profile

```
PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

After applying those changes with ". .bash_profile", "which mysql" only outputs

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

How do i get mysql to also look at /Applications/MAMP/... ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that mysql/bin is listed before the MAMP bin folder.  The path is being evaluated from left to right, meaning that because `which` found `mysql` in the `mysql/bin` folder it is returning that one, without ever processing the other directories.

If you want the mysql binary to be found from the MAMP binary folder, then switch the order of your PATH to `PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Yes I did that, but is it not possible for it to return both paths? After doing that switch, mysql which returns the MAMP binary folder and not the local one. If not, would a symlink do the trick?

Comment: Not unless you make a symlink to the desired binary:  for example if you create a symlink to the MAMP mysql binary and name it mamp_mysql and leave your original path alone, calling `which mamp_mysql` will return one folder, and `which mysql` will return the other